# ProGuard - Difference between keep package and keep classes

Tags: android, proguard

Consider only 2 classes called A and B, and the following statements:

```
-keep class mypackage.* { *; }
```

```
-keep class mypackage.A { *; }
-keep class mypackage.B { *; }
```

What are the possible differences between the two code blocks? I believe they should mean the same, but my app only runs with the first statement. Thanks.

EDIT:

I've fixed the issue thanks to T. Neidhart. If anyone has the same issue, the difference is that the second code block was missing inner classes that were still being obfuscated. Adding  *  fixed things for me:

```
-keep class mypackage.A* { *; }
-keep class mypackage.B* { *; }
```

-Cheers

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to run keeping specific classes?

Comment: @DeeV java.lang.AssertionError is the error that I'm getting. From the stack trace, it is not coming from A or B.

Comment: Do the classes A or B have inner classes as well? That might explain the difference.

Comment: @T.Neidhart Ayy what do you know, that was the problem. My app runs fine now, thank you!